# Google Chrome Remote Desktop generate pin using Linux console

Tags: linux, google-chrome, chrome-remote-desktop

Right now `Google Chrome Remote Desktop` does not allow to add whole machine to the computers list. So it is impossible to access computer that does not manually generate PIN code.

I have a SSH access to the remote machine which has installed above plugin. Is it possible to generate PIN using terminal ?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem, so I wrote a shell script to do just what you are asking.  You log in over ssh and run this script, and it automatically clicks the clicks to start up chrome on your (still invisible) display and return you the access code at the ssh terminal.  You can cut/paste this code into the RD from on your chrome client, and it connects up.  See my wiki page at http://zeus.phys.uconn.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_start_a_Chrome_Remote_Desktop_session_on_Linux#The_chromote.sh_script

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no unless there is some undocumented headless interface for Google Chrome extensions.

But if you got SSH running you can install a VNC server on the target, and then tunnel a VNC connection through SSH and get a visual desktop this way. You'll need to forward port 5901 (by default you will be running on the first virtual desktop) and then point your vnc client (e.g. tightvnc) to 127.0.0.1:1 (or 127.0.0.1:0 if you'll be using the real desktop via x11vnc).

Then you will be able to set a PIN in Chrome Remote Desktop visually. And then laugh at the whole setup of having to use VNC to connect via Chrome RD, but this is how I tested that the Chrome client actually works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution posted on askubuntu [by Wernight](https://askubuntu.com/a/953269/740127).

One not involving anything like VNC.

Once you've run

```
/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host --code="MY_AUTH_CODE" \
--redirect-url=https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/blank \
--name="MY_REMOTE_NAME"
```

you'll be prompted to enter a PIN and, shortly, the machine should show up in your CRD client.